# How to send a double value from fragment to other

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a dialog fragment which pass a double value to a other fragment by using interface but in my other fragment it getting invalid double value.

Interface:

```
public interface Receive {

    public void onDataReceive(Double out);
}
```

my fragment1:

```
public class InputFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private Receive mData;
    EditText ed;
    RadioButton rb1,rb2;
    Button b1,b2;


    public InputFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mData = (Receive)activity;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void sendDataToFrag(){
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!ed.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    if (rb1.isChecked()) {
                        int input = Integer.valueOf(ed.getText().toString());
                        double out = input / 24.0;
                        out = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#.0").format(out));
                        mData.onDataReceive(out);
                    } else if (rb2.isChecked()) {
                        int input = Integer.valueOf(ed.getText().toString());
                        double out = ((input * 2 / 3) * 0.029574);
                        out = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#.0").format(out));
                        mData.onDataReceive(out);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input, container, false);
        ed = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        rb1 = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        rb2 = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        b1 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        b2 = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.confirm);

        sendDataToFrag();
        return view;
    }
```

In my main activity calling interface:

```
@Override
public void onDataReceive(Double out) {
            MainScreen mainScreen = (MainScreen) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ms);
            mainScreen.getData(out);
}
```

In my another fragment2:

public void getData(double out) {
        result = Double.toString(out);  I take double to string

```
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_screen, container, false);
    mainScreen = this;
    textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.res);
    textView.setText(result);
    ram = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText().toString()); // here I'm retrieving string to a double but getting exception invalid double..
```

exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.cloudicalabs.waterfinder.water_rem, PID: 2883
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
  at com.cloudicalabs.waterfinder.water_rem.MainScreen.onCreateView(MainScreen.java:42)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to check the input from `textView`

1) Don't forget to check `null` for prevent NullPointerException.

```
if (null != textView.getText()) {
    //...
}
```

2) Don't forget to check `empty` string to prevent NumberFormatException.

```
if (!textView.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    //...
}
```

Finally, the code for parse double:

```
public View createView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    ram = getDouble(textView);
}

private double getDouble(TextView textView) {
    double result = 0.0;
    if (null != textView.getText() && !textView.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        try {
           result = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText().toString());
       } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    return result;
}
```

A ha, I find something was wrong here.
The communication between your fragments does not smooth.
Currently, I've seen that:

1) InputFragment will get input and invoke callback of Activity.

2) Activity send result to Fragment MainScreen

3) You want to show data from onCreateView of MainScreen.

The problem is occurred due to step 3.
To solve it. We have two option:

1) If the MainScreen is attached before user type input: you should update data on method `getData`

```
public void getData(double out) { 
   ram = out;
   // do something with ram (ex: set to textview)
}
```

2) if the MainScreen is not attached before user type input, you should send data directly to MainScreen before you attached it to your activity

Comment: I tried  but showing a null object reference in my   @Override
public void onDataReceive(Double out) {
            MainScreen mainScreen = (MainScreen) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ms);
            mainScreen.getData(out);   and  in my fragment 1 :    mData.onDataReceive(out);

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
   ram= Double.valueOf(textView.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   inp = 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried  but showing a null object reference in my   @Override
public void onDataReceive(Double out) {
            MainScreen mainScreen = (MainScreen) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ms);
            mainScreen.getData(out);   and  in my fragment 1 :    mData.onDataReceive(out);

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Remove code`ram = Double.parseDouble(textView.getText().toString());`

And replace with below code,

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
ram = getDoubleValue(text);
```

Add below method in your class

```
    private double getDoubleValue(String text) {
       Double value = 0.0;
       try {
           value = Double.parseDouble(text);
       } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when the `onCreateView` method executed, the `getData` has not be called. So the value of `result` always be `""` when `onCreateView` method executed.

Try this:

```
public void getData(double out) {
    ram = out;
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(out));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_screen, container, false);
    mainScreen = this;
    textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.res);
    // ...
}
```